# Geometry - Divide 3D points into segments with specific angle

Tags: python, geometry, computational-geometry, angle, point-clouds

I have a cloud of points with the form of a `cylinder(x, y, z)` like the picture:.

[image: cylinder]

I want to divide it into 3D segments within a specific angle.

It looks like I have a pie and I need to cut it into pieces.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you know the axis of the cylinder ?

Comment: yes, the center is in (0,0,0)

Comment: I said the axis, not just the center.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, this is how you can do what you want using https://github.com/daavoo/pyntcloud and using as example [this cylinder](https://github.com/fracture91/graphics-hw3/blob/master/meshes/cylinder.ply) in .ply format.

You can load the cylinder:

```
from pyntcloud import PyntCloud
cylinder = PyntCloud.from_file("cylinder.ply")
```

Wich is a triangular mesh that look like this:

[image: cylinder mesh]

You can generate a point cloud from the mesh as follows (this step is not necesary if you already have the cylinder as a point cloud):

```
n_points = 100000
cylinder = cylinder.get_sample(
    "mesh_random_sampling",
     n=n_points,
     as_PyntCloud=True)
```

Wich now looks like this:

[image: cylinder point cloud]

Now comes what I think is the right approach to do the "pie segmentation".

You can convert the (x, y, z) cartesian coordinates to (ro, phi, z) cylindrical coordinates as follows:

```
cylinder.add_scalar_field("cylindrical_coords")
```

The "phi" scalar field is a value wich identifies each point with the angle that you were interested in. The visualization is more explanatory:

[image: cylinder phi scalar field]

You can now use this phi values to divide the points into the desired number of segments:

```
import pandas as pd
n_segments = 3
cylinder.points["segment"] = pd.cut(
    cylinder.points["phi"],
    n_segments, 
    labels=range(n_segments))
```

Now cylinder.points["segment"] has a unique value assigning each point to a "pie segment".

The visualization is usefull again to appreciate the "pie segments":

[image: cylinder pie segment]

Answer (score 0):

Get:
- base point O - center of cylinder circle base, lying in plane L
- cylinder axis unit vector N
- base vector V in the plane L, collinear to some cut direction
- the second base U, perpendicular to N and V  `(U = N x V)`

Then for every point P from cloud make its projection onto plane and find corresponding vector

```
P' = P - N * ((P-O).dot.N)
W = P'-O
```

and get angle (and sector) relative to V in the plane using

```
angle = atan2(W.dot.U, W.dot.V)
```